# Exploring Ghost Recon maps offline

Tags: ghost-recon-phantoms

Is there a way to explore Ghost Recon Phantom maps offline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to explore maps offline.

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully this does not sound redundant but there a way to explore the map with out joining a public game?  For example, can a clan have practice with say just a handful of people, 4 or 5? Thanks.

Comment: you can all join a fireteam and then go into a game together, but you will still be matched up against other players. There is no private lobbies yet in the game either.